# When is a Grothendieck construction a presheaf category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, grothendieck-construction

Let $C$ be a small category, $\mathcal{P}C$ its presheaf category, and $F:\mathcal{P}C^{\rm op} \to \rm Cat$ a pseudofunctor.  Are there general conditions we can impose ensuring that the Grothendieck construction $\int F$ is also a presheaf category?

I'm happy to assume, for instance, that each category $F(X)$ is a presheaf category, say $\mathcal{P} (D_X)$, and that each transition functor $F(f) : F(Y) \to F(X)$ is induced by some functor $D_X\to D_Y$.  In this case there is an induced pseudofunctor $D : C \to \rm Cat$, so one might conjecture that $\int F$ is $\mathcal{P}(\int D)$.  But I don't immediately see any reason to expect that to be true except that $\int D$ is the only small category in sight.

It also seems reasonable to assume some kind of accessibility or cocontinuity of $F$, or even some sort of p.r.a. or weak representability condition.  (For instance, Makkai and Pare proved that if $E$ is accessible and $F:E^{\rm op} \to \rm Acc$ is accessible, then $\int F$ is again accessible.  Thus, if $E$ is locally presentable and $F$ lands in locally presentable categories and right adjoints, then $\int F$ is locally presentable.  How can we improve this to presheaf-ness?)

Finally, I'd be interested both in answers about 1-categories and in answers about $(\infty,1)$-categories.  It seems possible that the latter might have a nicer answer, e.g. because cocontinuity of $F$ could then be related to the free-cocompletion property of $\mathcal{P} C$ (for 1-categories there would be a dimension mismatch here).

Comment: Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes: the construction of https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06275 shows that if $D$ is a finite direct category, then $\mathcal{P}D$ can be obtained as the Grothendieck construction of a certain pseudofunctor $F:\mathcal{P}C^{\rm op} \to \rm Cat$, where $C$ is the discrete category on the degree-0 objects of $D$, and each category $F(X)$ is the category of presheaves on a "derivative" direct category of height one less than that of $D$.  So I wonder if there is a general condition satisfied by this $F$ "explaining" why $\int F = \mathcal{P}D$ happens to be a presheaf category.

Comment: One natural source of fibrations between presheaf categories would be applying the 2-functor $Set^{(-)^{op}}$ to various cofibrations in $Cat$. Perhaps the fibration you're interested in arises from applying $Set^{(-)^{op}}$ to the endcap inclusion of a collage or something?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, that's certainly a different way to argue that the particular functor in my example is a fibration: the inclusion of the degree-0 objects of a direct category is one of the inclusions of a collage.  But that's not the question I'm asking now, I want a characterization of when the total category of a fibration is a presheaf category in terms of properties of the corresponding pseudofunctor.

Comment: Why?  Well, in the same mentioned paper we studied a more general class of categories constructed by iterated Grothendieck constructions.  A good answer to this might give a way to characterize the presheaves on direct categories among those in this more general class.